# Does the dataset WriteXml(string fileName) method rewrite the whole datset to a file or just appends the changes?

Tags: c#, dataset

I am using datasets WriteXml method to write changes on to a local file for persistancy.
I am willing to pay the penalty for the I/O but cannot figure if each time that i call WriteXml the whole dataset is rewritten to file.
Does anybody know if this is the case? And if so what can i do to just append the latest row?

Answer (score 1):

I think it will rewritten the whole dataset to the file.
To just append, I suppose you have to manipulate your DataSet for a sub-Dataset contains only the latest row, and go from there.